# Access child component's providers in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

Say I have a component which uses a 3rd party component from Github which defines it's own providers.

```html
<my-component>
    <awesome-contrib-component></awesome-contrib-component>
</my-component>
```

and for the `awesome-contrib-component` providers:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'awesome-contrib-component',
    providers: [FooProvider]
})
```

As far as I can tell, even if I provide `FooProvider` at the app bootstrap level or even on `my-component` (with either providers or viewProviders), since `awesome-contrib-component` specifies it's own providers, it's always getting it's own instance.

The problem is that in `my-component` I need access to the *same* instance of `FooProvider` that is used by`awesome-contrib-component` and I'm not able to get it.

Is this possible at all? Am I missing something? Thanks!

The important thing to stress here is that `awesome-contrib-component` is a 3rd party module from Github, it defines it's own providers and assigns `FooProvider` to itself as a private variable and doesn't expose it.

As someone using this 3rd-party library short of opening a PR (which I did) I'm not sure how to work around this.

Comment: Are you talking about @ViewChild? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/ViewChild-var.html

Comment: @AndreyKartashov yes, if the component referenced in ViewChild doesn't expose it's providers as a public property, is there any way for me to access it?

Answer (score 3):

Use `@ViewChild`, or if you have multiple children use `@Children`, like this

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [AwesomeContribComponent]
})
export class MyComponent{
  @ViewChild(AwesomeContribComponent) public childInstance: AwesomeContribComponent

  ngAfterViewInit(){
     console.log(this.childInstance.fooProvider); // you got the service
  }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'awesome-contrib-component',
    providers: [FooProvider]
})
export class AwesomeContribComponent {
  constructor(public fooProvider: FooProvider){}
}
```

Comment: So the thing to stress here is that it's a contributed 3rd-party module and it already defines it's own provider and assigns it privately in it's constructor.  I have no way to change it from the inside out.

Comment: in my knowledge, NO.  see if you can ask the developer to provide it as output or make it public.

Answer (score 2):

You are definitely missing something, yes ! :)

So if you want the same provider instance into the child and the parent, then you just provide it in the parent component(NOT in the child), in the child you just use it (without provide) so you will have the same instance.

More on providers/dependency injection/ services : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection.html

Comment: It's a 3rd party component, so I can't change the fact that it has it's own provider set up!

Comment: oh, then I don't think you are missing anything. It's a weird situation indeed, probably that 3rd party component should expose some things with the **@input()** metadata or something.